# iterating through html elements with ruby mechanize

Tags: ruby, arrays, web-scraping, mechanize

I may be way off even in my approach to what I am trying to do but here is what I got.

Id like to gather fantasy football projections and place all the html elements(for different players) into an array and iterate through them to display the result.

```
require 'mechanize'

mechanize = Mechanize.new

dk_qb = mechanize.get('http://www.numberfire.com/nfl/fantasy/fantasy-football-projections/qb')



dk_qb_array = ['#container > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.fl.clearfix > h2',
            '#container > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.fl.clearfix > h2']

dk_qb_array.each do |name|
 require 'mechanize'
 mechanize = Mechanize.new

 dk_qb = mechanize.get('http://www.numberfire.com/nfl/fantasy/fantasy-football-projections/qb')

 puts "#{dk_qb}.at('#{name}').text.strip"
```

end

```
returns ==> #<Mechanize::Page:0x007f9ed95058f0>.at('#container > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.fl.clearfix > h2').text.strip

            #<Mechanize::Page:0x007f9ed91382e0>.at('#container > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.fl.clearfix > h2').text.strip
```

I got it working one at a time, but any advice on iterating through more elements would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to require mechanize again here:

```
dk_qb_array.each do |name|
  require 'mechanize'
```

In any case, you should be using Nokogiri--not Mechanize:

```
$ gem install nokogiri
```

Then:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

selectors = [
  '#container > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.fl.clearfix > h2',
  '#container > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.fl.clearfix > h2',
]
url = 'http://www.numberfire.com/nfl/fantasy/fantasy-football-projections/qb'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

selectors.each do |selector|
  puts selector
  doc.css(selector).each do |matching_tag|
    puts "\t #{matching_tag.text}"
  end
end


--output:--
#container > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.fl.clearfix > h2
     Week 1 Fantasy Football QB Projections
#container > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.fl.clearfix > h2
```

As you can see from the output, there were no matches for your second selector; and the single match for your first selector is probably not what you want.  There is only one `<h2>` on the whole page, so looking for as second one isn't going to work.

A better approach would be to use an id attribute to go straight to the area you want, e.g.

```
"tbody#projection-data > tr"
```

and then do something like this:

```
doc.css("tbody#projection-data > tr").each do |tr|
  #The <tr> contains the data for one player

  tr.css('td').each do |td|  #Now step through the <td>'s for the given <tr>/player
    puts td.text.strip
  end

  puts '-' * 10  #Marks the end of the data for one <tr>/player

  #Now, loop back up and get the next <tr>/player
end


--output:--
Drew Brees (QB, NO)
ATL
#26
1
1
27.49/40.64
335.01
3.07
0.71
2.84
10.42
0.06
17.4-33.58
25.49
29.33
$0
0
26.25
$0
0
25.54
$0
0
25.54
$0
0
26.25
$0
0
----------
Peyton Manning (QB, DEN)
...
...
```

Comment: It's actually a bit cleaner with mechanize, but either way is fine.